# Could not find or load main class (module)

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm trying to create a jar with a main class that's located in one of my two modules. However, the created jar doesn't contain my specified main class.

My project structure is like this
MyProject

- first-module
- - src > main > java > com.example > MyClass
- - pom.xml
- second-module
- - src > main > java > com.example.util > Lots of classes
- - pom.xml
- pom.xml

I make use of the `maven-assembly-plugin` to create this jar. The snippet below is located in the project's root pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.example.MyClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This creates the jar inside MyProject/target folder. But when inspecting this jar with the `jar tvf <file>` command, I only see the Manifest.mf file inside of it. What would be the cause of this class located in first-module not appearing in the jar?

Comment: Please show the full pom file ..in particular where the maven-assembly-plugin is used?

Comment: @khmarbaise Please see my edit

Comment: Ok exactly what I expected. That simply does not work. You have to make a separate module which contains the dependencies to the given moduls you have and the configuration for your maven-assmbly-plugin also needed to know to define the packaging of that module to `pom` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people in the future: it turns out I needed to use the jar file created in the target folder of the first-module. Before I realised this, I kept using the jar created in the target folder located in the root folder.
In the first-module is `MyClass` located. And thus the jar from first-module's target folder is able to find and load the specified main class in my root pom.xml.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).